# Ruby Thread Still Blocking

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm running a single thread to put 'data' onto the screen.
The point of the thread was to stop blocking on this function so I could send data to the socket while listening to data on it's way back.

```
def msg_loop()
    t1 = Thread.new{
            loop do
            msg = @socket.recv(30)
            self.msg_dis(msg)
            end
        }
        t1.join
end
```

However if I run

```
myclass.msg_loop
myclass.send_msg("message to send")
```

The function send_msg is never run, no different than if msg_loop had no threading.

Comment: Perhaps you want an Actor model? See http://rubini.us/doc/en/systems/concurrency/ or http://celluloid.io/ for info.

Answer (score 2):

`t1.join` causes the program to wait until thread t1 has finished running. You want to do this instead.

```
def msg_loop()
  t1 = Thread.new{
        loop do
        msg = @socket.recv(30)
        self.msg_dis(msg)
        end
  }
  t1
end

t1 = myclass.msg_loop
myclass.send_msg("message to send")
t1.join
```

Comment: The function is defined within a class so I'm unable to call t1.join outside the class. I could send my message and then receive but then I can't send anything else. I need to have constant printing to my screen as I send data out.

Comment: in that case you might want to try omitting `t1.join`

Comment: if I don't run t1.join then I can send but I still can't see what's coming back my way. So I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Ruby doesn't provide real threading (jruby does).
With an infinite loop such as mine threading in ruby doesn't do anything because the loop never ends.

This causes the thread to never and and thus blocking occurs.

Comment: *Ruby doesn't provide real threading (jruby does)* Incorrect. Since Ruby 1.9 (YARV, C Ruby) supports native OS threads. And that's not the cause. It's because of `Thread#join` immediately called and that's unrelated to green/native threads topic.

Comment: Ruby threads are complicated beasts. The GIL is written in such a way that a Ruby operation that is implemented as a C function that makes no callbacks to any Ruby methods, will always be executed atomically. Looping constructs do not fulfil this condition. Any operation that does not fulfil this condition can be stopped and another operation on another thread can be given a change to run. This means that while you can't have real parallel threading (even if you have multiple processors), you can in fact have multiple threads have their operations be executed in slices.